# Which C++ Profiler to use?

Tags: c++, profiler

I am supporting a C/Cpp application and have resolved few memory leak issues by creating objects. Since it is provided by the third party API, it is told that the objects gets destructed by the API itself.

I could manage to fix the issue and test my application without any issue. But i still doubt my fix for memory leak. I want to do profiling and i am in need of a Cpp tool that can tell me if there are chances of memory leaks in the code given a CPP file.

Is there a tool of that sort? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
~Jegan

Comment: You probably are looking for a (static/dynamic) code analysis tool, not a profiler.

Comment: Wait what are you trying to do? How do you know there's memory leaks? If the third party library says it cleans up its objects, shouldn't you trust it? If not, why use it?

Comment: Solving this would be akin to solving the Halting problem. If you make good use of RAII and pointer design you will never leak memory.

Comment: @Falmarri: in the world of closed standards third party dlls are often the only way to support a protocol or data format. So you have to use a DLL, regardless of whether it can be trusted or not.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for a dynamic analysis tools, not a profile. For Linux, there's [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). For windows some good commercial solutions are [Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) and [Insure++](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/home.jsp?product=Insure).

Comment: Static analysers, e.g. Insure++ can find problems like this as well. And you could also mention cppcheck.

Answer (score 4):

Give [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) a try, it's by far the best memory analysis tool I've come across. It only runs on *nix, but you haven't stated your platform.

Answer (score 1):

We're using MemoryValidator from http://www.softwareverify.com/.
It provides a fully functional 30 day trial, so you can test it before buying.
Single license from 179$ (each for 10 licenses), up to 299$ (1 license). And it is really worth it's price. Enables you to find the cause for leaks within a minute.

Also check the other tools they're providing: performance validator, bug validator and so on.

Great tool once you know how to handle it :-)